# Bridge two NICs

Tags: networking

(I know next to nothing about networking, so bear with me.)

I have a Linux board with two NICs. One will only be connected to another board, the other will connect to a network. I need to make the other board able to reach the network, likely broadcast UPD onto that network and have things connect back to it.

What could be done to bridge those two NICs so the other board can reach the network?

Comment: There's at least 5 different ways (seriously - network manager, classic ifup config, netplan, dhcpd (as raspberry pis do...)) to do network config in linux, dependent on Distribution and even version. They all configure differently. What's this board, and what does it run?

Comment: @TechSteveBrule you might want to look into "bridge-utilities" https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge and patch your /etc/network/interfaces accordingly

Comment: @mcantsin That only applies to Debian and some Debian-based distros. Hence the question from JourneymanGeek. What distro are you running? It makes all the difference, config-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It's a custom board based on an arm imx6 running an image built with yocto.